# Fastest way to create multiple copies of a list

Tags: python, numpy

### Problem

I am working on a breadth-first search algorithm for my maze solver and it is working so far. I am keeping track of the current stack by copying the previous one and appending the current value to it.

Since copying list takes a great amount of time I would like to create multiple copies of the list within one operation.

### What I've tried so far

- Copy the list and assign it to multiple variables.

  ```
  l = [1, 2, 3]
  a = b = c = l[:]  # Just creates references and no individual lists
  ```
- Use numpy arrays with `copy` function (faster than `list[:]`).

### Question

What is the fastest way to create multiple copies of one list?

Comment: Do you really need lists? I usually go for a [spaghetti stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent_pointer_tree) for applications like this and only build a list once I've found the goal, if I need a list.

Comment: You're using `l[:]`, so I assume you want a shallow copy?

Comment: @user2357112 I do not need lists necessarily. Which datastructure would I use the keep track of such a stack? A dictionary?

Comment: @jsmolka: I've posted an answer describing how you'd do it with a spaghetti stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use ordinary Python lists for your stacks. Use Lisp-style linked lists, so your stacks share most of their structure with each other and building a new stack with an additional element is constant time:

```
def empty_stack():
    return ()
def push(stack, item):
    return (item, stack)
def stack_to_list(stack):
    l = []
    while stack:
        item, stack = stack
        l.append(item)
    return l[::-1]
```

Here, `push` runs in constant time and produces a new stack, without mutating the old, so you can call `push` on the old stack repeatedly without copying it.

Comment: Can I ask, what this is? Are you modelling a stack with python?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: It's a stack implementation where an empty stack is represented by an empty tuple and a non-empty stack is represented as a `(top item, stack containing the rest of the items)` pair. It's probably more familiar if you have experience with a functional language; in some functional languages, it's even the language's core data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can just bulk copy it:

```
def copyList(thelist, number_of_copies):
    return tuple(thelist[:] for _ in xrange(number_of_copies))

a, b, c = copyList(range(10), 3)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/K9gC/0)

Comment: @Avión, it is jut because of the unpacking, if you use more the either you capture all the copies in the tuple in a variable or you unpack with more variables.